# Email is not sent using Google Mail Server - Laravel 5.4

Tags: email, laravel-5

I am using Google Mail server (14 trails and will buy 5$/month) with digitalocean hosting. https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html?tab_activeEl=tabset-companies

Below .env is as below:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=passwordofinfo@mydomain.com
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

When send it from local computer, the mail sending function works well. But When I upload the website to server, I got below error with mail sending function:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try mail driver or sendmail instead of smtp

> MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

to

> MAIL_DRIVER= mail or sendmail